# Get sum of the salary for each user

Tags: django, django-models

I am on a django project where the admin assigns work to users by uploading the work to each user, and the user can only see the job they have been assigned to.
I want a way to get the total amount for all the work the user have done by the end of a month.
I have a model Work, and it has a field Pay_Amount, which is the amount for one job, I want a way to add the Pay_Amount of only one user per month.
I already have the total amount to pay all the users, I just want the amount to pay a single user for all the jobs he/she has done for one month...

My model

```
class work (models.Model):
    Date_Created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    Worker = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Reference_ID = models.CharField(primary_key=True, unique=True ,max_length=5000)
    Topic = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Reference_link = models.TextField(default=None,null=True, blank=True)
    Instructions = models.TextField()
    
    Note = models.TextField(default=None,null=True, blank=True)
    Deadline = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    
    Pay_Amont = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Hi. Share related code, so we can help you.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code..

Answer (score 0):

If you have `User` object, that you get i.e. with that function:

```
user = User.objects.get(id=1)
```

Then you might have get all the total related work objects:

```
user.work_set.all()
```

To sum total `Pay_amount`:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
user.work_set.aggregate(Sum("Pay_amount")).get("Pay_amount__sum")
```

And to limit that to one month (let's say August this year):

```
user.work_set.filter(Date_Created__month=8, Date_Created__year=2022).aggregate(Sum("Pay_amount")).get("Pay_amount__sum")
```

PS name classes with `CamelCase` and fields/variables with `snake_case`. It is pretty important.